# replace unneeded spaces with commas in txt using batch

Tags: string, batch-file

I have a text file that contains some information and looks like this:
7253    198760.294  533963.581
7373    198752.213  533954.046
739CT   198751.288  533952.902

In every line there are parameters that has spaces between them but the spaces (not tabs) are for ease or reading only.

I need it to look like this:
1550,168040.682,630305.751,
1575,168023.241,630287.837,
15964TS,168008.317,630272.508,

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in (input.txt) do (
  set "content=!content!%%x!LF!"
)

:loop
if defined content (
  set "new=!content:  = !"
  if "!new!" neq "!content!" (
    set "content=!new!"
    goto :loop
  )
)
if defined content if "!str:~0,1!" equ " " set "content=!str:~1!"
if defined content if "!str:~-1!" equ " " set "content=!str:~0,-1!"

echo(!content!
set string=!content! & echo !string: =,! > output.txt
endlocal

pause > null
```

It turns everything in one line and connects between everything without spaces.

Comment: Please post the text sample data as text here rather than as images, so others can easily copy them and use them for testing their prospective answers they are working on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation to a single string is dangerous, because of limited max string length. Better process each line on it's own:

```
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in (infile.txt) do ( 
    echo %%a,%%b,%%c,
))>outfile.txt
```

note: empty lines will be ignored (will get lost)

Comment: Thank you so much! You've helped me a lot!